# T-SQL CASE in WHERE Clause and IN operator

Tags: sql, t-sql

I trying to do this query where I have a where clause. The problem is that I need to use inside the `WHERE` condition the operator `IN`.

Anyone can help me?

Here is query. Thanks.

```
DECLARE @title As Varchar(10)

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE Title IN( CASE @title WHEN 'All' THEN  'FSOT','FSO','FISO','SFSO','PB','SPB' ELSE @title END)
```

Comment: So if @title = All then you need to pass a list, else just @title?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Operator in SQL Where Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568775/conditional-operator-in-sql-where-clause)

Comment: @Title got from a variable. For example in a UI there is DropDownList (All, FSOT, FSO, FISO, etc), If I'm selecting 'All' so @Title='All' and pass title list above, and if one of list other than 'All' selected so @Title='selected title'. TQ.

Answer (score 1):

No need for case expression, just use boolean logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE (@title = 'All'
      AND title IN ('FSOT', 'FSO', 'FISO', 'SFSO', 'PB', 'SPB')
      )
  OR (@title <> 'All'
      AND title = @title
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior with the logical `or` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   employee
WHERE  (@title = 'All' AND Title IN ('FSOT', 'FSO', 'FISO', 'SFSO', 'PB', 'SPB')) OR
       (@title != 'All' AND Title = @title)
```