# SQL how to include conditional in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server query that filters some data using:

```
and datepart(mm,cs.timestamp) <= @month
```

I have a parameter `@accumulate` that if `true` then I want to to above logic but if `false` then I want to do:

```
and datepart(mm,cs.timestamp) = @month
```

Any clue on how to that in same line?

Comment: Can you show all of the code? You might be better off using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Similar question to consider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568775/conditional-operator-in-sql-where-clause

Comment: Not an answer to your question, more of a comment on coding style. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little more concise, that could be one line

```
(DATEPART(mm,cs.timestamp) = @month 
 OR (@accumulate = 1 AND DATEPART(mm, cs.timestamp) < @month))
```

or, with a nod to Sean's comment (which is good advice)

```
(DATEPART(MONTH,cs.timestamp) = @month 
 OR (@accumulate = 1 AND DATEPART(MONTH, cs.timestamp) < @month))
```

or, if you want a short but opaque and nasty bit of code (and @accumulate is a bit)

```
SIGN(@month - DATEPART(MONTH, cs.timestamp)) in (0, @accumulate)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you can do it in one line.  But you could do it in multiple lines like:

```
and ( ( datepart(mm,cs.timestamp) <= @month and @accumulate = true )
   or ( datepart(mm.cs.timestamp) = @month and @accummulate = false ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use stored procedure with `IF` and `THEN` statement to separate the two conditions